# Programmatically end editing on all jeditable instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

My page has several jeditable instances in it. When my user clicks a finish button i'd like to be able to end editing on any jeditable instances that are still in edit mode. I can programmatically end editing by using .reset() which is the same as clicking the cancel buttons. I'd like to perform similar on the OK buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to programmatically click all the OK buttons and reset them, e.g.

```
$('.editable :submit').click();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Eqt7h/